# update sql database with ContentValues and the update-method

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I would like to update my SQL lite database with the native update-method of the SQLiteDatabase class of android.

```
ContentValues dataToInsert = new ContentValues();                          
dataToInsert.put("name", "flo");
dataToInsert.put("location", "flotown");
String where = "id" + "=" + id;
try{    
    db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, dataToInsert, where, null);
}
catch (Exception e){
    String error =  e.getMessage().toString();
}
```

but I get following error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "15": syntax error: ,
>   while compiling: UPDATE mytable SET location=?, name=? WHERE
>   id=2010-09-21 15:05:36.995

I don´t know what should be the problem. Somehow the values do not arrive in the SQL statement. I did nearly the same with the insert method and that worked quite fine.

Comment: I know this is old post but you should never user "id" use "_id" instead.  "_id" is a common id for databases in Android and recomended.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're using the update function wrong. It should be like this:

```
String where = "id=?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};

db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, dataToInsert, where, whereArgs);
```

The Strings in the whereArgs array gets substituted in for each '?' in the where variable.

ie. if you had where = "name=? AND type=? then the first '?' would get replaced by whereArgs[0] and the second by whereArgs[1].

Comment: "Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type long"

Comment: @Mirko: Use `Long.toString(id)` instead!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you just need to add apostrophes to your where clause. So it ought to be:

```
String where = "id='" + id + "'"
```

(note: however, this is not best practice, as it theoretically leaves open to injection attacks)

Answer (score 1):

I have an other approach

```
    public boolean updateEmployee(TalebeDataUser fav) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, fav.getId());
    contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUM_AD, fav.getAd());
    contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_NUMARA, fav.getNumara());
    contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_YURD_ID, fav.getYurtID());
    contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_EGITIM_ID, fav.getEgitimTur());
    contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_TEL, fav.getTel());
    contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL, fav.getEmail());
    contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ADDRESS, fav.getAdres());

    String whereClause = DBHelper.COLUM_AD + " = ? AND " + DBHelper.COLUMN_NUMARA + " = ? ";
    final String whereArgs[] = {fav.getAd(), String.valueOf(fav.getNumara())};// old nameler taranıyor
    int affectedRows = database.update(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_OGR, contentValues, whereClause, whereArgs);
    return affectedRows > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what exactly you written is correct. The syntax is correct.
But you have to check these. 
    String where = "id" + "=" + id;
In the above declaration "id" should be type number and id should be int.
And if id is a type of TEXT then follow @Adam javin answer.