# how to add data in the database on button click?

Tags: android, database

I am new to Android following is my code I wants to add data in data base on the click of button but when I click on the Button my application crashes
can anybody suggest me any solution
here is my code:

```
public class Third extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button btn;
SQLiteDatabase db;
EditText edit1;
EditText edit2;
EditText edit3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.mit);
SQLiteDatabase db;
db = openOrCreateDatabase("doctorinfo.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
db.setVersion(1);
db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
db.setLockingEnabled(true);
final String CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRIES ="CREATE TABLE med_d ("+ "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ "DOC_NAME TEXT,"+ "DOC_NO TEXT,"+ "DOC_EMAIL TEXT);";
//db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRIES);
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
edit1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
edit2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
edit3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

btn.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
String d=edit1.getText().toString();
String m=edit2.getText().toString();
String p=edit3.getText().toString();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("DOC_NAME",d );
values.put("DOC_NO",m);
values.put("DOC_EMAIL",p);
//long countryId = db.insert("med_d", null, values);
//try {
db.insertOrThrow("med_d", null,values);
}// catch (Exception e) {
//Log.e("Add Error", e.toString());
//e.printStackTrace();
//}



}
```

Comment: what is the error on logcat.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SQLITEOPENHELPER CLASS**

```
package com.db.demo;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

/**
 * Subclass of the {@link SQLiteOpenHelper} that sets up the database for the
 * demo.
 * 
 * @author Kah
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "CursorDemo", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names ("
            + BaseColumns._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, first VARCHAR, last VARCHAR)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO names (first, last) VALUES ('John', 'Doe')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO names (first, last) VALUES ('James', 'Kirk')");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Steps to upgrade the database for the new version ...
}
```

}

****Activity class****

```
package com.db.demo;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class DataHandlingActivity extends ListActivity{
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
 String fields[] = { "first", "last", BaseColumns._ID };
    private CursorAdapter dataSource;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor data = database.query("names", fields, null, null, null, null,
            null);

    dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data, fields,
            new int[] { R.id.first, R.id.last });

    ListView view = getListView();
    view.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
    view.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null));

    setListAdapter(dataSource);
}
```

}

use something like this in button click and change activity class
[update sql database with ContentValues and the update-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760774/update-sql-database-with-contentvalues-and-the-update-method)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use SqliteOpenHelper class to do all the database manipulation.

Please go through this link, this will give you some good tips.

http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-sqlite-database.html

Answer (score 1):

Put this method in your database helper class:

```
public long InsertRecord(String msg, String msg1,String msg2) {

    long d = 0;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(SMS_NO, msg);
    values.put(SMS_BODY, msg1);
            values.put(SMS_BODY, msg2);

    try {
        d = myDataBase.insert(SMS_TBL, null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return d;

}
```

after this in your activity's `onCreate` method you must put this code to create  thedatabase:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());


            try {
                dbHelper.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dbHelper.openDataBase();
                dbHelper.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
```

and finally in on btn click

```
btnBlock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String edittext = edittext.getText().toString();
            String edittext1 = edittext1.getText().toString();
                            String edittext2 = edittext2.getText().toString();

            dbHelper.InsertRecord(edittext,edittext1,edittext2);

        }
    });
```