# How do I make an update query in SQLite with where clause?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [update sql database with ContentValues and the update-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760774/update-sql-database-with-contentvalues-and-the-update-method)

I am using this code, but I want update it according to my ID.

```
public void updateforgotpassword(String data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ContentValues forgotpass = new ContentValues();
        forgotpass.put("password", data);

        try {
            db.update(TABLE_NAME, forgotpass, null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String error = e.getMessage().toString();
        }

    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: refer to this post [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3874985/966550](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3874985/966550)

Comment: did you even try looking it up?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the row's ID is stored in the variable id and assuming that the column name is _id (which is standard), you can update like this

```
final String[] whereArgs = { Long.toString(id) };
db.update(TABLE_NAME, forgotpass, "_id = ?", whereArgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use rawquery method in which the plain SQL query can be fired.

Or, you can use the "update" method provided by SQlite and in which provide two array, one for "whereargs" and one is "wherevalue"

use

`"update [your table] set [your column]=value"` in rowQuery method...

or,

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, forgotpass, "KEY_ID = ?", whereArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of supplying a where clause.

db.update(TABLE_NAME, forgotpass, "ID = ?", new String[]{paramUserID});

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
        public boolean updateAccountData(AccountModel account) {

            boolean updated = false;
            openDataBase();
            try {
                final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put("AccountName", account.getAccountName());
                values.put("Lessee", account.getLessee());
                values.put("BookingRedeliveryNumber", account
                        .getBookingRedeliveryNumber());
                values.put("SurveyorName", account.getSurveyorName());
                values.put("ManufacturerName", account.getManufacturerName());
                values.put("State", account.getState());            
                values.put("TurnInMonth", account.getTurnInMonth());
                values.put("TurnInYear", account.getTurnInYear());
                values.put("CscMonth", account.getCscMonth());
                values.put("CscYear", account.getCscYear());

                myDataBase.update(ACCOUNT_MST, values, "AccountID = "
                        + account.getAccountID(), null);
                updated = true;
    }
return updated;
    }
```