# how to set an integer and a string value in android sqlite 'execSQL' statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to set an integer and a string value in execSQL statement :

```
mydb.execSQL("UPDATE emptable set age=? where name=?",new int[] {emp_age},new String[] {emp_name});
```

where emp_age is an integer and emp_name is a String. But this is not working.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, but I'm not happy with the given answers, and I'll explain why.

**@hotveryspicy** answer is not only ugly but also dangerous. I'll remind you of the possibility of an [SQL-injection](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection), which can cost you your stored data.
The same is true for **@john smith** answer.

**@user1318091** answer is incorrect for the same reason that makes all of these answers (including your given example-code) wrong. If you read the documentation, you'll notice that it says:

> Execute a single SQL statement that is **NOT** a
>   SELECT/INSERT/**UPDATE**/DELETE.

on the first line. It also lists alternatives for the above mentioned operations:

> For UPDATE statements, use any of the following instead.
>
> - update(String, ContentValues, String, String[])
> - updateWithOnConflict(String, ContentValues, String, String[], int)

If you choose to use the simple [`update()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), your query will look like this (untested!):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("age", age); // your integer...
mydb.update("emptable", values, "name=?", new String[]{emp_name});
```

Also check this question for the correct "where"-syntax: [update sql database with ContentValues and the update-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760774)

Comment: i appreciate, +1 goes to you. Thanks for giving such useful information.

Comment: i appreciate your answer. i had changed my code. And thanks for such useful info.

Answer (score 1):

the sdk says

> bindArgs: only byte[], String, Long and Double are supported in
>   bindArgs

But if you want to use bindArgs, then you can try this

```
mydb.execSQL("UPDATE emptable set age=? where name=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(emp_age)},new String[] {emp_name});
```

Comment: So, the value of "String.valueOf(emp_age)" will be a perfect Integer or Integer stored as string ??

Answer (score -1):

```
 String sql = "UPDATE emptable  SET age = "+age + " WHERE name = '" + emp_name + "';";
 db.execSQL(sql);
```