# SQLite syntax Error on UPDATE

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I have a database Scheme in SQLite database as:

```
CREATE TABLE AppRecord ( sno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, version Text,fields Text, appname    Text, appid Text, status Text, displayDetails Text, id Text);
```

i am trying to update my record with the following query

```
UPDATE AppRecord SET version ="16",
fields = "[{"lbl":"user","type":"text","required":true},
    {"lbl":"age","max":100,"type":"text", "number":true, "required":true,     "maxPrecision":2},
    {"lbl":"address","type":"text", "multiline":true},
    {"lbl":"date","type":"date","minDate":"3","maxDate":"3","required":true}]",
    appname = "Sales", 
    appid = "sales",
    status = "modified",
    id = "52860e0d012bad414cc98162" 
    WHERE appid = "sales";
```

Every time i try to do it, it is giving me a syntactical error saying:

`ERROR android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "lbl": syntax error (code 1)`

I tried my best to figure out the error but I am not able to resolve it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have unescaped `"` quotes. Better use `ContentValues` with `update()` or at least `?` literal substitution with raw SQL.

Comment: @laalto Sorry i am not getting which place i have skipped quotes

Comment: The value you're trying to update to `fields` contains `"` quotes.

Comment: @laalto thanks i read about Content value and ? literal in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760774/update-sql-database-with-contentvalues-and-the-update-method/6945092#6945092

itswoking thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to put a string value enclosed in `"` quotes in `fields` but the value also contains `"` quotes.

The SQL way to escape `"` is to double it as `""`:

```
sqlite> create table foo(bar);
sqlite> insert into foo values("string with ""quotes"" embedded");
sqlite> select * from foo;
string with "quotes" embedded
```

A better way is to use [parameter substitution](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam).

In Android Java API this can be using the `bindArgs` parameter of [`execSQL()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), or more conveniently for update queries, using [`update()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) with `ContentValues` (the `whereArg` does the same substitution for the `WHERE` part of the constructed update query).