# update a row of listview in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a StaggeredGridView populated from database by a baseadapter. I want to update contents of one row (one cell). But I am getting this error :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE ASSIS_NOTES_TABLE SET =?,ffhj=?,dfhj=? WHERE Assis_Note_Title=dfhj
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1572)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1520)
        at com.hirak.assistere_doit.tasks_Database_Operations.updatenote(tasks_Database_Operations.java:68)
        at com.hirak.assistere_doit.edit_note_frag.onClick(edit_note_frag.java:81)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below are my codes :

Fragment that has gridview : (on list item click, another fragment opens where user edit texts (everything is wirking fine upto here)

```
notesSGV.setOnItemClickListener(new StaggeredGridView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String edit_title = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.note_title_added)).getText().toString();
            String edit_note = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.notes_grid_text)).getText().toString();
            String color = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.color)).getText().toString();
            edit_note_frag editNoteFrag = new edit_note_frag();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("title", edit_title);
            b.putString("note", edit_note);
            b.putString("color", color);
            editNoteFrag.setArguments(b);
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.addToBackStack("eNF");
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);
            ft.replace(R.id.MainContent, editNoteFrag, "eNF");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

Fragment where user update items :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    title = getArguments().getString("title");
    note = getArguments().getString("note");
    color = getArguments().getString("color");
    iii = getArguments().getInt("id");
    edit_note.setText(note);
    edit_title.setText(title);
```

And then on button click in the same fragment, update is called :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == update){
        final tasks_Database_Operations tasksDatabaseOperations = new tasks_Database_Operations(getActivity());
        tasksDatabaseOperations.getWritableDatabase();
        tasksDatabaseOperations.updatenote(iii, title, note, color);
        tasksDatabaseOperations.close();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is the update query in the database class"

```
 public void updatenote(int id, String title, String note, String color) {
    this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(title, ASSIS_NOTES_TITLE);
    contentValues.put(note, ASSIS_NOTES);
    contentValues.put(color, ASSIS_NOTES_COLOR);
    sqLiteDatabase.update(ASSIS_NOTES_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ASSIS_NOTES_TITLE + "=" + title , null);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}
```

Comment: Thats **SQL syntax error**

Comment: i tried various syntaxes. nothing happened

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3874985/3049917 do like this 'public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)'

Comment: Update this:
 sqLiteDatabase.update(ASSIS_NOTES_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ASSIS_NOTES_TITLE + " = ?" + title , null);

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code and try this I hope it will help you.

```
sqLiteDatabase.update(ASSIS_NOTES_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ASSIS_NOTES_TITLE+"='" + title  + "'", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your Error log You are missing first colomn name in your query

```
UPDATE ASSIS_NOTES_TABLE SET =?,ffhj=?,dfhj=? WHERE Assis_Note_Title=dfhj
```

thats why showing error here`near "="`

`UPDATE ASSIS_NOTES_TABLE SET First=?,Second=?,Third=? WHERE Assis_Note_Title=dfhj` and so on.