# update database android doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i'm discovering database in Android. I understand how to read it but i don't succed writing it. Here is the database:

```
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table lesPlats
             (id integer primary key autoincrement, nom text not null, quantite integer);";
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
```

i edit it:

```
        values.put("nom", "plat1");
        values.put("quantite", 0);
        database.insert("lesPlats", null, values);
```

i want to increase the quantity of "plat1" (debug version in comment):

```
        int n=1;
     // Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lesPlats WHERE id="+n, null);
     // c.moveToFirst();
     // System.out.println("QUANTITY BEFORE: "+cursorToComment(c).quantite+ " (id: "+cursorToComment(c).id+")");

        database.rawQuery("UPDATE lesPlats SET quantite = 1 WHERE id = " + n, null);

     // c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lesPlats WHERE id="+n, null);
     // c.moveToFirst();
     // System.out.println("QUANTITY NEXT: "+cursorToComment(c).quantite+ " (id: "+cursorToComment(c).id+")");
```

with debugging, i got the result

QUANTITY BEFORE: 0 (id: 1)

QUANTITY NEXT: 0 (id: 1)

So there is a mistake somewhere. Could you tell me if the code is good? specially this one:

`database.rawQuery("UPDATE lesPlats SET quantite = 1 WHERE id = " + n, null);`

This means that quantity is set to 1 at the id=1, isn't it?
i try with UPDATE, i have the same result...

Comment: i forgot to describe the class stored in the databse:public class Comment {
    public long id;
    public String nom;
    public int quantite;

Comment: Not important, your question is a duplicate. See the solution in that post.

Comment: Though, you really shouldn't use rawQuery...  See here for the better solution http://stackoverflow.com/q/3760774/2308683

Comment: i try 
        values.put("quantite", 2 + cursorToComment(c).quantite);
        String Where = "id=?";
        String[] WhereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(n)};

        database.update(TABLE_PLATS, values, where, whereArgs);  there is no change

Comment: You need to move and close the cursor as described in the answer

Answer (score 0):

read and close the cursor before calling the second raw, because the query won't get executed without it :

```
c = database.rawQuery("UPDATE lesPlats SET quantite = 1 WHERE id = " + n, null);
c.moveToFirst();
c.close();
```

Comment: i try your code and database.execSQL("UPDATE lesPlats SET quantite = 1 WHERE id = " + n); but i have no change...

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys, i've forgot the to set quantity in the cursorToComment procedure...

```
private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    comment.setNom(cursor.getString(1));
    comment.setQqte(cursor.getInt(2));   //here!!
    return comment;
```

thx a lot

So, three ways to change the database:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("quantite", 1);
database.update("lesPlats", values, "id=?", new String[]{"1"});
```

or

```
database.execSQL("UPDATE lesPlats SET quantite = 1 WHERE id = " + n);
```

or

```
c = database.rawQuery("UPDATE lesPlats SET quantite = 1 WHERE id = " + n, null);
c.moveToFirst();
c.close();
```

pfiou!